# How to write multi data just one time?

Tags: mysql, sql

i can't solve SQL Query. Not, i have a database and table. This table had same data. I can count with this code:

```
SELECT ColoumbNameA, COUNT(*) 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY ColoumbNameA
```

And we will see this;

[image]

Now, we know UyeNumarasi=000717 is 4 times write. I want to this value be 1 in sql. How can i write Query?

Comment: What is your expected (desired) output here?

Comment: Question why should the output be 1 for UyeNumarasi=000717? The record number that contains UyeNumarasi=000717 is clearly 4 why do you want a other Value here?

Comment: For put on Crystal Report.

Comment: And you do want to keep the other values like they are?

Comment: Yes, i want but i want display just one time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems `distinct` is required

```
SELECT ColoumbNameA, COUNT(distinct value) 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY ColoumbNameA;
```